# Как найти похожие объявления по названию и описанию?

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, redux

Мне нужно написать функцию которая будет сравнивать одно объявление с массивом других объявлений и будет создавать массив с похожими объявлениями. Два объявления считаются похожими, если они содержат хотя бы одно и то же слово в заголовке и описании. Массив выглядит так:

```
[
   {title: "Test", description: "hello", id: 22},
   {title: "Test two", description: "hi", id: 49},
   {title: "Test three", description: "hello there", id: 100},
   {title: "Test four", description: "oh", id: 129},
]
```

Спасибо!

Answer (score 0):

```js
function getWords(msg) {
  var res = new Set()
  
  for (var key of ['title', 'description']) {
    for (var word of msg[key].match(/\w+/) || []) {
      res.add(word)
    }
  }
  
  return res
}

function indexMsgs(msgs) {
  var dict = new Map()

  for (var msg of all) {
    for (var word of getWords(msg)) {
      var cur = dict.get(word)
      if (!cur) dict.set(word, cur = [])
      cur.push(msg)
    }
  }
  
  return dict
}

var all = [
   {title: "Test", description: "hello", id: 22},
   {title: "Test two", description: "hi", id: 49},
   {title: "Test three", description: "hello there", id: 100},
   {title: "Test four", description: "oh", id: 129},
]

var dict = indexMsgs(all)

function getSimilar(msg) {
  return [...new Set([...getWords(msg)].flatMap(x => dict.get(x) || []))]
}

console.log(getSimilar(all[0]))
console.log(getSimilar({ title: "oh", description: "" }))
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100vh }
```